# Remove duplicate entries in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, duplicates, uitextfield

I have to remove duplicate entries while entering values in UITextField.
Is there a way to check for duplicates while entering in a UITextField ? Suppose I enter some text in a UITextField separated by a single space " ". I need to check "dynamically" if duplicates are entered. In other words is there a way to disable duplicates in a UITextField ?

Comment: Not natively, no. You are going to have to come up with your own logic to do something like this. Also if you want to do it "dynamically" you are proabably going to want to use the delegate methods to receive updates on user input in the text field (i.e. `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`)

Comment: The logic I'm going to implement is as follow. The UITextField contains tags separated by single space " ". Implementing the method above I'm able to insert each tag from the UITextField into an array and display it into a UICollectionView where each cell width is dynamically set accordingly to the tag lenght. What I need to manage now is how to disable entering duplicated tags in such UITextField. Two ways I'm thinking about. Remove duplicates while entering or allow duplicates while entering first and remove duplicates when the user press "Done" button.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement UITextField action .editingChanged:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And check the text:

```
@objc
func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    guard let text = sender.text else { return }
    var finishedWords = text.components(separatedBy: " ").filter({ $0 != "" })
    var endOfResult = ""

    if text.last == " " {
        endOfResult = " "
    } else if !finishedWords.isEmpty {
        if finishedWords.count > 1 {
            endOfResult += " "
        }
        endOfResult += finishedWords.last ?? ""
        finishedWords.removeLast()
    }

    var seen = [String]()
    let uniqueWords = finishedWords.filter({ word in
        if seen.contains(word) {
            return false
        } else {
            seen.append(word)
            return true
        }
    })

    let result = uniqueWords.joined(separator: " ") + endOfResult
    sender.text = result
}
```

Comment: This code has several issues. 1. The `guard` assumes the cursor is at the end of the text field. The user could be making changing anywhere in the text field. 2. If, for example, the user entered the word "a", then this code will prevent the user from entering any other words that start with the letter "a". 3. Use `joined` to rebuild the string from the `words` array.

Comment: That should fix #1 and #3 but not #2.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I'm sorry. Now my code seems complex ).